# How to show uicollection view in ARSCNView in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, arkit

I am trying to implement uicollection view in arscnview and scroll direction horizontal with user interaction. 
In collection view cell contains product image and name. is it possible to add collection view arscnview.

Result which i got : [image]

here is the code i treid so far:

```
     let newCollection: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collection.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collection.isScrollEnabled = true
    return collection
}()

  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return }

   self.newCollection.delegate = self
            self.newCollection.dataSource = self
            self.newCollection.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.cellId)
            self.view.addSubview(self.newCollection)
            self.setupCollection()

            let collectionPlane = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.1)
            collectionPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.newCollection

            let collectionNode = SCNNode(geometry: collectionPlane)
            collectionNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
            collectionNode.runAction(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 0))

            node.addChildNode(collectionNode)


                   self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)


   }

      //collection view

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = newCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 3, bottom: 3, right: 3)
}
```

expected output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the material's diffuse's contents property to the collectionView's view property

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = yourCollectionView.view
```